# how to align equation on page

Tags: equations

I created this equation in my thesis. But, it is too big. Half equation dont appear. How I can align it ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.0cm,rmargin=2.0cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{  {fig/} }
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \label{equacao_silica}
    \text{Quantidade de Sílica (wt\%)}
      = ( \text{Perda de Massa (580\degree C-900\degree C)} \times \frac{101,4}{44}) - ( \text{Perda de Massa (30\degree C-200\degree C)})- ( \text{Resíduos de GCC)})
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a *full* minimum working example (MWE), starting with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}`, that shows the problem, along with which packages are loaded, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the power of the `mathtools` package you are already loading.

First place the equation body in a `split`.  The general syntax is

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    First line left &= first line right \\
                    &= second line \\
                    &= third line
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

where the `&` indicate points that will be aligned vertically.

In your case the left hand side of the equation before the `=` is rather wide, so put it on a line on its own (without an `&`) and use `\MoveEqLeft` to move it to the left, thent add alignment points at the left end of subsequent lines.

You equation will need three lines in total.  The last, starting with a minus sign, should have an extra indentation relative to the previous line.  This can be provided via `&\qquad`, but it crops up so often I define an extra macro `\eqbreak`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.0cm,rmargin=2.0cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\newcommand{\eqbreak}[1][2]{\\&\hskip#1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{equacao_silica}
  \begin{split}
    \MoveEqLeft \text{Quantidade de Sílica (wt\%)} \\
    &= \Bigl( \text{Perda de Massa
    (\SI{580}{\degreeCelsius}-\SI{900}{\degreeCelsius})}
    \times \frac{101{,}4}{44}\Bigr)
    \eqbreak
    - \bigl(\text{Perda de Massa
    (\SI{30}{\degreeCelsius}-\SI{200}{\degreeCelsius})}\bigr) 
    - (\text{Resíduos de GCC})
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Other changes made

- use of `\SI` for numbers with units
- increased sizes of some brackets to improve grouping
- decimal comma written as `{,}`

Also note that `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so you do not need to load `amsmath` later.  However, see the [documentation of `amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) for many of the features it has for displayed equations and splitting them over several lines.

*Addition*: As Svend Tveskæg points out, the rewriting of the decimal comma can also be accomplished by using `\num` from `siuntx` with the appropriate locale.  This can be set globally by modifying the extra commands for a babel language.  Unfortunately there is no portuguese locale support, but I guess that french is the closest:

[image: Sample locale use]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\addto\extrasportuguese{\sisetup{locale = FR}}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\num{101,4}}{\num{44}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would use `\num[locale = DE]{104.4}` instead of `101{,}4`. (Maybe `locale = DE` should be declared globally.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Thanks, thats interesting.  I have updated my answer with a variation on that.

Comment: It should be `\num{101.4}` instead of `\num{101,4}`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Both will work (try changing removing the locale change).  For a native Portuguese speaker the comma will be most natural.

Comment: Good point. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You can cheat a little and use `\binom` to put your quantities into two lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{equacao_silica}
\binom{\text{Quantidade}}{\text{d Sílica (wt\%)}}
  = \binom{\text{Perda de Massa}}{\text{(580\degree C-900\degree C)}}
     \times \frac{101,4}{44} -
     \binom{\text{Perda de Massa}}{\text{(30\degree C-200\degree C)}}
     - ( \binom{\text{Resíduos}}{\text{de GCC)}})\\
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which gives this:

[image]

By playing around with this a little more your should be able to get the equation number in the right place (and fixing up the mathematics as your formula was hard to read and I think I got it slightly wrong).

However, I think that this is the wrong approach. Presumably `Quantidade de Sílica` is a function computing the amount of silicon and `Perda de Massa` is some sort of function computing the mass loss for the given temperature etc. So I think that it is much better practice to define these functions properly and then write your equation like this:

[image]

You probably have better (shorthand) notation of these functions, but you can typeset something along these lines with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\QS}{QS}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PM}{PM}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{equacao_silica}
\QS(wt\%) = \PM(500^\degree\text{C}-900^\degree\text{C})\times\frac{101,4}{44}
     -\PM(30^\degree\text{C}-200^\degree\text{C})- \Res
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The equation is simply too long to fit on a single line. You could use a `multline` environment to break it up across two lines or a nested `equation`/`split` environment to break it up across three lines. (I personally prefer the latter approach.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.0cm,rmargin=2.0cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{  {fig/} }
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multline}
    \label{equacao_silica}
    \text{Quantidade de Sílica (wt\%)}
      = \bigl( \text{Perda de Massa (580\degree C--900\degree C)}
        \bigr) \times \frac{101,4}{44} \\
      - \bigl( \text{Perda de Massa (30\degree C--200\degree C)} \bigr)
      - ( \text{Resíduos de GCC)}
    \end{multline}

    \begin{equation}\begin{split}
    \label{equacao_silica}
    \text{Quantidade de Sílica (wt\%)}
      &= \bigl( \text{Perda de Massa (580\degree C--900\degree C)}
         \bigr) \times \frac{101,4}{44} \\
      &\quad - \bigl( \text{Perda de Massa (30\degree C--200\degree C)}\bigr)\\
      &\quad - ( \text{Resíduos de GCC)}
    \end{split}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of these solutions, with `multline`or `multlined`, the main difference being the placement of the equation number. Using the `siunitx` helps for a correct degree Celsius horizontal spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry} %

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\text{Quantidade de Sílica (wt\%)} =
\begin{multlined}[t]
\label{equacao_silica}
\text{(Perda de Massa)}\bigl(\SI{580}{\celsius} - \SI{900}{\celsius}\bigr) \times \frac{101,4}{44}\\[4pt]
- \text{(Perda de Massa)} \bigl(\SI{30}{\celsius } -\SI{200}{\celsius}\bigr)- \text{(Resíduos de GCC)})
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}

Or, if you prefer the number aligned with the second line:

\begin{multline}
\label{equacao_silica}
\text{Quantidade de Sílica (wt\%)} =\text{(Perda de Massa)}\bigl(\SI{580}{\celsius} - \SI{900}{\celsius}\bigr) \times \frac{101,4}{44}\\
- \text{(Perda de Massa)} \bigl(\SI{30}{\celsius } -\SI{200}{\celsius}\bigr)- \text{(Resíduos de GCC)})
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect the `-` between the two temperatures is *not* a "minus" sign. Instead, it is probably (the OP might provide definitive clarification...) a range indicator -- "loss of mass between 589 degrees and 900 degrees" -- and should thus probably be typeset as a text-mode en-dash.

Comment: @Mico: I wondered, but thought it wasn't compatible with the product with a fraction in the first term. May be I was not fanciful enough:)

Comment: Let's hope the OP provides some clarification...